# Dimension Reduction with Map reduce, using distributed computing?

Tags: mapreduce, distributed-computing

Do you know an application or algorithm to reduce dimensionality of big data, maybe using `Map-Reduce`, or other `api`, also:

- Do you know some algorithms like
  `Singular Value decomposition` than
  can be useful to reduce dimention of
  data sets
- how to use distributed computing to
  solve this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) because SVD is implemented in there.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Mahout, you should take a look at [SLEPc](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/) (which is a toolkit based on [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/)) for solving eigenvalue problems for very large sparse matrices.  It uses MPI, so it will run on lots of different parallel and distributed architectures.  There's also [Gensim](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/), written in Python.  It's probably not as scalable as either Mahout or SLEPc but it's much easier to use.